# How to send a HTTP header on all server blocks in nginx?

Tags: nginx, http-headers

Let's say I have a running nginx instance with several server blocks (on a linux server), and that I would like to send an extra HTTP header like `Permissions-Policy: interest-cohort=()` on all responses because I agree with [Google's FLOC being a bad idea](https://plausible.io/blog/google-floc).

I know this can be done on a per-server block basis (by editing each of my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/*` files one by one) by adding something like

```
server {
    location / {
        add_header Permissions-Policy interest-cohort=();
        # ...other stuff
    }
    # ...other stuff
}
```

Is it possible to configure this extra HTTP header for all locations of all server blocks **at once**? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [nginx docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header), yes:

> Syntax:  **add_header** name value [always];
> Default:  —
> Context:  http, server, location, if in location
>
> Adds the specified field to a response header provided that the
> response code equals 200, 201 (1.3.10), 204, 206, 301, 302, 303, 304,
> 307 (1.1.16, 1.0.13), or 308 (1.13.0). Parameter value can contain
> variables.
>
> There could be several add_header directives. These directives are
> inherited from the previous configuration level if and only if there
> are no add_header directives defined on the current level.
>
> If the always parameter is specified (1.7.5), the header field will be
> added regardless of the response code.

by putting in `http` it will apply to all `server` blocks.

Comment: Yeah, that works. Note to self: read the docs before going wild on stackexchange.